# Recent Posts+, how to solve multiwidget?

Tags: plugins

I have installed the Recent Posts plugin, that came with a widget. Now, i can only add one instance of the widget to the widget areas. I want one instance to show in my widgetarea that only appears on my startpage, and one instance of the widget to my widgetarea that appears on other pages.

Now, the widget doesnt seem to support "multiwidget", but the "widget instances" are supposed to have the exact same configuration. Is there any way to "Force" WP into adding the widget to my other widget area too, even if it means "hacking" the DB?

Comment: A link to the specific plugin you're using would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, Anton!
You don't have to hack the database...

Probably you can find a replacement for this plugin that uses the modern [Widgets_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), responsible for the multi-instance widgets. At least as far as I know, because haven't worked much with WordPress pre-2.8.

If you are willing to hack something, hack the plugin using the examples of the Codex.

As for showing one widget in the Front Page and other in the rest, use the plugin [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/). It is very simple and effective.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by merging the two widget-areas into the same and use Widget Logic to control which should be shown